# Generic code to determine how many rows from a table are in a different table with matching structure?

Tags: sql, linq

How can I create a generic function in C# (LINQ-to-SQL) or SQL that takes two tables with matching structure and counts how many rows in TableA that are in TableB.

```
TableA Structure
Value1, Value2

TableA Data
1,1

TableB Structure
Value1, Value2

TableB Data
1,1,
1,2
```

To get count of matching rows between TableA and TableB:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB ON
TableA.Value1 = TableB.Value1 AND
TableA.Value2 = TableB.Value2
```

The result in this example

```
1
```

So the query above works great, but I don't want to have to write a version of it for every pair of tables I want to do this for since the INNER JOIN is on *every* field.  I feel like there should be a more generic way to do this instead having to manually type out all of the join conditions.  Thoughts?

Edit: Actually, I think I'll need a C#/LINQ answer since this will be done across servers.  Again, this is annoying because I have to write the code to compare each field manually.

```
var tableARows = dbA.TableA.ToList();
var tableBRows = dbB.TableB.ToList();
var match = 0;
foreach(tableARow in tableARows){
    if(tableBRows.Where(a=>a.Value1 = tableARow.Value1 && a.Value2 = tableARow.Value2).Any()){
        match++;
    }
}

return match;
```

Comment: "this will be done across servers" Then it's not really a sql/linq question... you'll have to load the table data and compare the rows locally.

Answer (score 1):

using sql server this will work

```
 var sql="select count(0) from(
    select * from product except select * from product1
    ) as aa";
```

dc = dtataContext

```
var match= dc.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the join using syscolumns.

```
declare @tablenameA varchar(50) = 'tableA'
declare @tablenameB varchar(50) = 'tableB'

declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
select @sql =''
select @sql = @sql + ' and ' + quotename(@tablenameA )+ '.' 
       + c.name +' = ' + quotename(@tablenameB )+ '.' + c.name
from syscolumns c 
    inner join sysobjects o on c.id = o.id
where o.name = @tablenameA

select @sql = 'select count(*) from ' + @tablenameA + ' inner join '+@tablenameB+' on '
     + substring (@sql, 5, len(@sql))

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You query the ANSI INFORMATION_SCHEMA views, thus:

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col
where col.TABLE_SCHEMA = <your-schema-name-here>
  and col.TABLE_NAME   = <your-table-name-here>
order by col.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

against each of the tables involved. The result set will provide everything needed for your to construct the required query on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

One fairly simple answer:

```
select ( select count(*) from 
              (select * from TableA UNION ALL select * from TableB) a ) - 
       ( select count(*) from 
              (select * from TableA UNION select * from TableB) d ) duplicates
```